# C# Sequential file output

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `C# winform` application that is outputting to excel files.
Let's say the name format of the file name is: `Output1.xlsl`

I would like to have the output saved to another sequential file on each button click/execution.
So next it would be `Output2.xlsl`, `Output3.xlsl`... etc.

How to check that, I know of checking if the file exists, but how to check for the numbering?

```
FileInfo newExcelFile = new FileInfo(@"Output1.xlsx");
if (newExcelFile.Exists)
{
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this loop and [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx):

```
string directory = @"C:\SomeDirectory";
string fileName = @"Output{0}.xlsx";
int num = 1;
while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(directory, string.Format(fileName, num))))
    num++;
var newExcelFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(directory, string.Format(fileName, num)));
```

In general  the static `File` methods are more efficient than always creating a `FileInfo` instance.

Answer (score 2):

We use a method similar to this to achieve this:

```
/// <param name="strNewPath">ex: c:\</param>
/// <param name="strFileName">ex: Output.xlsx</param>
/// <returns>Next available filename, ex: Output3.xlsx</returns>
public static string GetValidFileName(string strNewPath, string strFileName)
{
    var strFileNameNoExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFileName);
    var strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);
    var intCount = 1; 
    while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(strNewPath, strFileNameNoExt + intCount + strExtension)))
        intCount++;
    return Path.Combine(strNewPath, strFileNameNoExt + intCount + strExtension);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it in a while loop

```
int num = 1;
FileInfo newExcelFile = new FileInfo("Output1.xlsx");
while(newExcelFile.Exists)
{
    newExcelFile = new FileInfo("Output" + num + ".xlsx");
    num++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would find the newest file in the folder and use its number as a basis to start from.  If there are no other programs to write there, this should be sufficient.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("Some folder");
            FileInfo fi = di.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(s => s.CreationTime).First();
            string fileName = fi.Name;
```

//....

Comment: You have a good idea but your sample code seems to have a bug.  You are getting the earliest (creation time) file, so you won't be saving any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple loop:

```
FileInfo newExcelFile = null;
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    newExcelFile = new FileInfo(string.Format(@"Output{0}.xlsx", i));
    if (!newExcelFile.Exists)
    {
        break;
    }
    newExcelFile = null;
}
if (newExcelFile == null)
{
    // do you want to try 2147483647
    // or show an error message
    // or throw an exception?
}
else
{
    // save your file
}
```

Comment: Note that you *may* need to initialize `newExcelFile` to `null` in case the compiler gives an error.

Comment: `i` can never exceed `int.MaxValue` so if there were 2B files then the loop would either never end/become negative or throw an exception (if checked).

Comment: @KevinBrock great, didn't proof-read and think carefully. But at least I have a check which most other answers don't.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be most efficient one but I can suggest following solution

1. split the file name with "."
2. Remove substring "Output" from it
3. Now sort to get the maximum number.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the logic. What should happen if you had `Output1.xlsx` `Output2.xlsx` `Output3.xlsx` and removed `Output2.xlsx`, should the new file be `Output2.xlsx` or `Output4.xlsx`?
If you want to have always the highest number for the new files, you can use similar code

```
        int lastNum = 0;

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\myDir", "Output*.xlsx");
        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            Array.Sort(files);
            lastNum = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(files[files.Length - 1], "Output[\\d](*).xlsx").Result("$1"));
            lastNum++;
        }

        FileInfo newExcelFile = new FileInfo("Output" + lastNum + ".xlsx");
```

Of course you can loop, but it's not a good idea if you have thousands of files. For small amount of files it could be fine

```
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < Int32.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            if (File.Exists("Output" + i + ".xlsx"))
                break;
        }
```